# LINQ to SQL - Why can't you use a WHERE after an ORDER BY?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The following code:

```
// select all orders
var orders = from o in FoodOrders
             where o.STATUS = 1
             order by o.ORDER_DATE descending
             select o;

// if customer id is specified, only select orders from specific customer
if (customerID!=null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(o => customerID.Equals(o.CUSTOMER_ID));
}
```

gives me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I fixed the error by doing the sorting at the end:

```
// select all orders
var orders = from o in FoodOrders
             where o.STATUS = 1
             select o;

// if customer id is specified, only select orders from specific customer
if (customerID!=null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(o => customerID.Equals(o.CUSTOMER_ID));
}

// I'm forced to do the ordering here
orders = orders.OrderBy(o => o.ORDER_DATE).Reverse();
```

But I'm wondering why is this limitation in place?  What's the reason the API was designed in such a way that you can't add a `where` constraint after using an `order by` operator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The return type of `OrderBy` is `IOrderedQueryable<T>`, so that's the type of the `orders` variable (partly because you have a no-op projection at the end) - but the return type of `Where` is just `IQueryable<T>`. Basically you've got a mixture of a no-op projection *and* an implicitly typed local variable *and* the last active part of the query is an ordering, *and* you're then wanting to reassign the variable. It's an unhappy combination, basically.

You could fix it like this:

```
IQuerable<FoodOrders> orders = from o in FoodOrders
                               where o.STATUS == 1
                               order by o.ORDER_DATE descending
                               select o;

// if customer id is specified, only select orders from specific customer
if (customerID!=null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(o => customerID.Equals(o.CUSTOMER_ID));
}
```

Alternatively, if you performed the no-op projection explicitly using dot notation (I suspect the SQL translator will be smart enough to cope!) the type inference would be okay:

```
var orders = FoodOrders.Where(o => o.STATUS == 1)
                       .OrderByDescending(o => o.ORDER_DATE)
                       .Select(o => o);

// if customer id is specified, only select orders from specific customer
if (customerID!=null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(o => customerID.Equals(o.CUSTOMER_ID));
}
```

Or as a final and slightly odd suggestion, you could just change the order of your initial `where` and `orderby` clauses. This would be a bad idea in LINQ to Objects, but shouldn't make a difference in LINQ to SQL:

```
var orders = from o in FoodOrders
             order by o.ORDER_DATE descending
             where o.STATUS == 1
             select o;

// if customer id is specified, only select orders from specific customer
if (customerID!=null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(o => customerID.Equals(o.CUSTOMER_ID));
}
```

Now, in terms of the "why" of the API design: `OrderBy` and `OrderByDescending` return `IOrderedQueryable` so that you can then chain it with `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` which rely on there being an existing ordering that they can become secondary to, if you see what I mean.

Comment: This is a really thorough answer and a great explanation.  Thanks.

Comment: @MCS: I meant a no-op projection - a select clause which just selects what's already there, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Ok - now I got it.  If the select operator wouldn't be no-op - for example, if I had used select o.ORDER_ID instead of select o - the orders var would be converted back to an IQueryable for me and I wouldn't have any type conversion issues.

Comment: I was going to look up what you meant with degenerate query, but you seem to have gotten rid of that term while I was on my way home :)

Comment: @Thorarin: A *denegerate query* is one of the form `from x in y select x` - in that case a `Select` call *is* still emitted, whereas `from x in y where x.Foo == 1 select x` will only emit a `Where` call. I used it incorrectly in this post.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that var is strongly typed and gets interpretted at compile time. Your first code snippet it essentially the same as:

```
IOrderedQueryable<FoodOrders> orders = from o in FoodOrders 
         where o.STATUS = 1 
         order by o.ORDER_DATE descending 
         select o;
```

When you write the code this way it becomes obvious why you can't assign an IQueryable to a variable declared as IOrderedQueryable.

You can't think of var in the same way you would object

```
object aString = "Testing...";
var bString = "Testing...";

aString = 1; // Works
bString = 1; // Fails because 1 is not a string
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx