# Having trouble trying to order using linq

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I am trying to order by start date(s.StartDate). Below is my code so far, my understanding is that I should be adding `.orderby(s.StartDate)` somewhere but I don't think I'm even taking the correct route now as I have tried many ways.

```
var query = from s in context.SessionSearch 
            where s.Children == 0 && s.IsPublic == isPublic
            select s;

var query = from s in context.SessionSearch 
            where s.Children == 0 && s.IsPublic == isPublic

if (startDate != null)
{
  query = query.Where(s => s.StartDate >= startDate && s.StartDate <= endDate);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to start with the "without startdate" option - you have a couple of options here - either declare the type of the query specifically:

```
IQueryable<SessionSearch> query = from s in context.SessionSearch
            where s.Children == 0 && s.IsPublic == isPublic
            order by s.StartDate
            select s;
```

And then as you've tried, add the additional `where` clause to the query if there's a start date passed in:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.StartDate >= startDate && s.StartDate <= endDate);
```

This means that you would not be able to add further ordering via the `ThenBy` methods.

Alternatively, you can add the `order by` clause after you've finished adding the where clauses:

```
var query = from s in context.SessionSearch
            where s.Children == 0 && s.IsPublic == isPublic
            select s;

if (startDate != null) {
  query = query.Where(s => s.StartDate >= startDate && s.StartDate <= endDate);
}

query = query.OrderBy(s => s.StartDate);
```

Props to [JonSkeet for pointing these out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2999413/33051).

Comment: Thanks for your help. The orderby s.StartDate is what i have also tried. I wasnt sure if that was correct but thanks! I am getting a error message i am guessing this is because its a datetime. error message is Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<test.test.Core.SessionSearch>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<test.test.Core.SessionSearch>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\account\Source\Repos\testExtensions\src\test.test.Data.EF\SessionRepository.cs 89 25 test.test.Data.EF

Comment: Ah, that error's not caused by the fact that s.StartDate is a DateTime, it's caused by [the issues here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999413/33051). I'll update.